# How to schedule emails for query results from TFS 2015?

Tags: .net, tfs, azure-devops, tfs-2015

I have created a few queries in TFS giving me the results containing the work items of my interest, and the one which I manage. 
My requirement is very simple - I want the results of those particular queries in my mailbox every morning.
Is there any out of box feature? Or do I need to write some programs for this?
I am using TFS 2015.

Any idea on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a small PowerShell script that'll run this query using [TFS REST API](https://www.visualstudio.com/integrate/api/wit/wiql#Runaquery) and send the results by email.

Then you add a scheduled job that'll execute that script every morning.

Answer (score 4):

No, there is no out of box feature for this. Current you can only email the query result from Web Portal or Team Explorer manually. There is already a feature request on VSTS User Voice: [Send email with query results on a schedule](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/10546863-send-email-with-query-results-on-a-schedule). Please vote it up.

For now, the alternative way would be using VSTS API to create an App to get and email the query request on schedule.

Answer (score 1):

I have written a small open source utility, which allows you to do that.
Basically it accepts some TFS settings (TFS url, TFS project guid, and the query guid), and some mail settings (email and such, and your smtp server), and do exactly that.

https://github.com/idanpl/tfs-query-reporter

If you want to binaries, just go to the output directory.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I have created a free extension for that, and it is available in the [Marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Quadrotech.ADOScheduledWorkItemQuery) and on [GitHub](https://github.com/Quadrotech/ADOScheduledWorkItemQuery).

It allows you to create an Azure Pipeline with a Task that is able to send out E-Mails. All you need is either [SendGrid](https://sendgrid.com) or an SMTP Server.